# What am I missing in my SQL script?

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL, and I am struggling to see what I've missed in this script.

Each time I try to run it, it takes ages and ends up with an error due to insufficient memory.

```
select r.CONSTITUENT_ID
     , case when r.SEX = '1'then 'Male'
           when r.SEX = '2' then 'Female' else 'Unknown'end as Gender
     , case when r.KEY_INDICATOR = 'O' then 'Organisation'
            when r.KEY_INDICATOR = 'I' then 'Individual'end as record_Classification
     , case when cc.CODE = '1924' then 'Bristol Affiliated'
            when cc.CODE = '1963' then 'Gloucester Affiliated'
            when cc.CODE = '2045' then 'Wiltshire Affiliated'
            else 'n/a' end as DW_Affiliation
from RECORDS r, CONSTITUENT_CODES cc
```

Comment: A JOIN condition perhaps? (E.g WHERE r.cc_code = cc.code?)

Comment: You're creating a Cartesian Product between two tables with this query (all possible results between all columns in the two tables).  Use a proper `JOIN` syntax to relate the two tables on a shared key(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
from RECORDS r,CONSTITUENT_CODES cc`
```

is cross join what means `show me every row from RECORDS with every row CONSTITUENT_CODES` so it returns [rows number from RECORDS]*[rows number from CONSTITUENT_CODES ] rows.
You have to use `join` or `where`  to eliminate `cross join`

```
from RECORDS r,CONSTITUENT_CODES cc
where r.column  = cc.column
```

or

```
from RECORDS r
join CONSTITUENT_CODES cc on r.column  = cc.column
```

I don't know your table structure but maybe this will work

```
select r.CONSTITUENT_ID
     , case when r.SEX = '1'then 'Male'
           when r.SEX = '2' then 'Female' else 'Unknown'end as Gender
     , case when r.KEY_INDICATOR = 'O' then 'Organisation'
            when r.KEY_INDICATOR = 'I' then 'Individual'end as record_Classification
     , case when cc.CODE = '1924' then 'Bristol Affiliated'
            when cc.CODE = '1963' then 'Gloucester Affiliated'
            when cc.CODE = '2045' then 'Wiltshire Affiliated'
            else 'n/a' end as DW_Affiliation
from RECORDS r, CONSTITUENT_CODES cc
where r.CONSTITUENT_ID = cc.CONSTITUENT_ID
```

with recommended join style it looks like

```
select r.CONSTITUENT_ID
     , case when r.SEX = '1'then 'Male'
           when r.SEX = '2' then 'Female' else 'Unknown'end as Gender
     , case when r.KEY_INDICATOR = 'O' then 'Organisation'
            when r.KEY_INDICATOR = 'I' then 'Individual'end as record_Classification
     , case when cc.CODE = '1924' then 'Bristol Affiliated'
            when cc.CODE = '1963' then 'Gloucester Affiliated'
            when cc.CODE = '2045' then 'Wiltshire Affiliated'
            else 'n/a' end as DW_Affiliation
from RECORDS r 
join CONSTITUENT_CODES cc on r.CONSTITUENT_ID = cc.CONSTITUENT_ID
```

I see in `RECORDS` is `CONSTITUENT_ID` this column can be use to join with column id from `CONSTITUENT_CODES` - I guess `CONSTITUENT_ID`

Comment: It's not deprecated... SQL-2011: <from clause> ::=
FROM <table reference list>
<table reference list> ::=
<table reference> [ { <comma> <table reference> }... ]

Comment: a join was exactly what was missing, I've added an inner join for 'constituent_codes' so my code is now ending
'from RECORDS r
inner join CONSTITUENT_CODES cc
on r.ID = cc.CONSTIT_ID'

Thank You